# Redmine Internal error when clicking on Create button

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I am getting redmine internal error page whenever I try to create a new issue with Tracker type "CODE REVIEW".AS soon as i click on CREATE button its redirected to "Internal Error Page"..But the issue will be assigned to the assignee.
And also if I create New Tracker,I am facing the same problem whenever I create a New ISsue.
I have not installed any plugin.But still I am getting this problem.Please help me out.
When I saw production log i get below error.Please help me out

```
Running before_save custom workflows for issue "redmine" (#)
Running before_save custom workflow "Due date Validation"
Running before_save custom workflow "Is Assignee?"
Running before_save custom workflow "Automating % Done ratio"
Finished running before_save custom workflows for issue "redmine" (#).


Rendered mailer/_issue.text.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered mailer/issue_add.text.erb within layouts/mailer (3.1ms)
  Rendered mailer/_issue.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered mailer/issue_add.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1.3ms)

Email delivery error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
 Running after_save custom workflows for issue "redmine" (#47061)
 Running after_save custom workflow "Due date Validation"
 Running after_save custom workflow "Is Assignee?"
 Running after_save custom workflow "Automating % Done ratio"
 Finished running after_save custom workflows for issue "redmine" (#47061).
 Running before_save custom workflows for issue "redmine" (#47061)
 Running before_save custom workflow "Due date Validation"
 Running before_save custom workflow "Is Assignee?"
User workflow error: Whoa!! You are not the assignee
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 841.2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:164:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:152:in `create'
```

Comment: Look logs. If Redmine works at your computer, find it in /redmine_app_dir/log, if at hosting, see hosting documentation about getting application logs. If You will not understand logged errors, add them to question.

Comment: When I saw production log I got this error..
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 841.2ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:164:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:152:in `create'

Comment: I have done small changes in multi time tracker plugin( removed a single line code in multi time tracker/app/views).Is it due to that changes ?But again I have added that single line code and checked.But still getting same error.

Comment: Try disable modified plugin.
Try debug in any IDE.
And give code where errors are receiving, line numbers says nothing - we may have different Redmine versions.